# D3 - resizable chart with brush

Tags: d3.js, responsive

I've created a timeseries chart with brush selection based on [MB's example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172) however I am trying to make my chart resizable.

I need the brush selection to persist between resize's so that the "focus" chart is showing the same data range before and after a resize event.

I believe I need to save the selection (as t1, t2) and then re-apply it after all elements have been resized but I'm not sure of the best way to achieve this.

I've read [the documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-brush) and can't find any suggestion regarding programatically getting/setting the selection from t values.

I gather a call to `brush.move` will be necessary:

```
  context.select("g.brush")
    .call(brush)
    .call(brush.move, x.range());
```

but i'm not sure how to modify this to regain the previous selection.

In-case it helps, I've created a fiddle which is working, except for the brush selection which resets on every resize.

https://jsfiddle.net/vdqg4rsm/12/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, on resize - record the ratio of change in width:

```
  var widthBefore = width;
  width = svgWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
```

and then, determine the current brush selection

```
  var brushSelection = null;
  var brushNode = context.select("g.brush").node();
  if (brushNode)
    brushSelection = d3.brushSelection(brushNode);
```

modify the selection according to the ratio of change

```
  if (brushSelection) {
    brushSelection = brushSelection.map(function(x) {
      return x * (width / widthBefore);
    });
  }
```

if there isn't a selection, fallback to something valid

```
  else
    brushSelection = x.range();
```

then apply this to the brush

```
  context.select("g.brush")
    .call(brush)
    .call(brush.move, brushSelection);
```